# How to make onclick event to work only once

Tags: javascript, popup

what I want to do is when someone click anywhere in the page.
A new window will open, but I want this to happen only once, so when someone click again on body, the function should not run.
Any advice? No jquery please.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onclick="myFunction()">
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        window.open("http://www.w3schools.com");
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try having a global javascript variable. Let this value initially be false. Before opening the window, check the value of this variable. Open the window only if the value of this variable is false. Once you open the window, set it to true.

Comment: use a global variable

Comment: 1: global boolean variable, 2: remove onclick event when running myFunction, 3: ... can't think of a third option

Comment: Sadly, none of the answers here work if preventing the user from clicking again takes longer than it takes the user to perform another click. E.g., if the user clicks very quickly (either purposefully or accidentally) multiple times before we either remove the `onclick` from the element or check the value of a global variable, then multiple clicks will be registered. Haven't found a solution to this yet.

Answer (score 20):

A short solution:

```
<body onclick="myFunction(); this.onclick=null;">
```

Check it:

```html
<button onclick="myFunction(); this.onclick=null;">This button works only once</button>
<button onclick="myFunction()">This button works always</button>

<script>

    function myFunction() {
        console.log("hello");
    }

</script>

</body>
```

Comment: Simple and effecient. Does it work even on old browsers like IE?

Comment: Thanks buddy you made my day

Answer (score 15):

Using ["once" in the "options" parameter for the `addEventListener` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Parameters) is unironically enough a great way of using a function once.

```
function myFunction(){
    console.log("hey")
}

document.body.addEventListener("click", myFunction,{once:true})
```

Answer (score 9):

There are couple of ways to do it.

1.Add event listener to body in the script and then remove once clicked.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
    document.body.addEventListener('click', myFunction);
    function myFunction() {
        window.open("http://www.w3schools.com");
        document.body.removeEventListener('click', myFunction);
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

2.Have a flag to check if the function was already called.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onclick="myFunction()">
<script>
    var isBodyClicked = false;
    function myFunction() {
      if(isBodyClicked === false){
        window.open("http://www.w3schools.com");
        document.body.removeEventListener('click', myFunction);
      }
      isBodyClicked = true;
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tested second one and worked quite well for me, thank you!

Comment: Technically, there are race conditions, but hopefully, it should be fairly unlikely for them to occur.

Answer (score 2):

The below uses an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) to create a closure holding the boolean variable and avoid populating global name space, explicitly attach a function to global object `window` and check if it's the first time the function is fired

```
function(){
    var firstTime = true;
    window.myFunction = function() {
        if (firstTime){
            firstTime = false;
            window.open("http://www.w3schools.com");
        }
    }
}()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function load() {
    document.body.removeEventListener('click', load)
    window.open('https://google.com/', '_blank')
  }

  window.onload = function() {
    document.body.addEventListener('click', load)
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is JQuery code.

We can use bind() unbind() / on() off() as below to avoid multiple click.

OR

We can use one() function to happen click only once.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').bind('click', function () {
        alert('button clicked');
        $(this).unbind('click');
    });
});
```

OR

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').one('click', function () {
        alert('button clicked');
    });
});
```