# Javascript - Trigger OnClick only once if QueryString present

Tags: javascript

I am looking to trigger an OnClick event, only once, if a querystring is present in the URL.

Ex:

```js
var QueryString = window.location.search;
if (QueryString) {
  document.getElementById("abc").click();
}
```

```html
<a href="" onclick="alert('clicked')" id="abc">click this</a>
```

Which this code, if there is a querystring present, it does fire the OnClick event, but seems to repeat the cycle (after I click OK on the alert, in this case). I'm looking to fire the OnClick event only once.

Thank you!

Comment: Check this question, I hope that helped you .
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38781349/how-to-make-onclick-event-to-work-only-once

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make onclick event to work only once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38781349/how-to-make-onclick-event-to-work-only-once)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The problem**

Programmatically clicking the `<a>` tag creates a navigation loop:

1. `href=""` is not the absence of a link and uses `window.location` as the link address.
2. `window.location` contains a query string.
3. A query string in a URL being navigated to generally requires the browser to reload the page from the server without using cached copies.
4. Both the first page load and reloading it executes the script code.
5. The script code issues an alert, and after being dismissed, clicks the link element. This navigates to a URL with a query string.
6. Navigation repeats from step 3.

**Solutions**

Ways to solve the issue could include

- Provide a document fragment identifier in the `href` value, e.g. `href="#"`, in the link address. By design this prevents page reload during navigation even if `location.search` is non-empty. It will, however, navigate to the fragment identifier provided.
- Set `window.location.search` to the empty string before programatically clicking the anchor element. Although untested it is also so unusual that I wouldn't recommend doing so.
- Don't use an anchor tag for the clicked element (which can prevents unwanted scrolling effects), or
- Call `event.preventDefault` in the click event handler. As an untested example:

  ```
   <a href="" onclick="event=>{event.preventDefault(); alert("hi")}">click me"</a>
  ```

  <sub>(disclaimer: addition of the event handler in this manner if for demonstration and is **not** "how to add an event handler for ongoing code use".)</sub>

Comment: I managed to solve the issue before this reply. 
I was so focused on the js part of the code, that I completely ignored the basic HREF="" part. This reply, however, does a great job at explaining the issue, and possible solutions. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can wrap the click event in a function and trigger this once the query string is present.

```
<a href="" onclick="myFunctiion()" id="abc">click this</a>

<script type="text/javascript">

        function myFunction() {
            alert('clicked');
        }

        var QueryString = window.location.search;
        if (QueryString) {
            myFunction();
        } 
</script>
```