# Use one() in inline onclick attribute

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a function that is triggered on an inline `onclick`.

What I want is for that function to get called only once but don't know how to do that with an inline `onclick`. It's working at the moment but runs everytime the user clicks rather than just once.

This is how I have it:

`HTML`

```
<div class= "container" onclick="modal('#modal')"></div>
```

I have tried having it as a Jquery function as follows and remove the above click but that is not working either:

```
$(".container").on( "click", modal( '#modal') {
  alert( "The event happened!" );
});
```

Any idea how to make it so the function only runs once?

Thank you

Comment: Use .one not .on  And you should never ever use inline on* handlers

Comment: Refer : https://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: Remove the 'onclick' after the div has been clicked

Comment: I had it as one, doesn't work either. According the documentation can also be on() if you read the examples on that link

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make onclick event to work only once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38781349/how-to-make-onclick-event-to-work-only-once)

Comment: @RandomDeveloper go to the function random(){ ... //and at the end of your function declarations add this: `this.onclick=null`, and you're done!

Comment: thanks @BekimBacaj problem with that is that modal is a global function so I can't alter that, I'd have to use it within another function maybe or something similar? Hence why me wanting to use one() in the inline onclick attribute or other alternatives. Don't want to touch the modal function

Comment: @RandomDeveloper That's no problem either, give it an `id=onlyonce` and say: ` if( e.target.id == 'onlyonce' )this.onclick=null;` //so that the event listener doesn't get cleared by some other handler element of that same function call before it was used by this special one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to use [jQuery's `one()`](https://api.jquery.com/one/), you'll need to remove the `onclick` from the HTML, and change the JS to read:

```js
$( ".container" ).one( "click", function() {
  alert( "The event happened!" );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class= "container">Container</div>
```

This way, the `alert()` will only show on the **first click**.

---

If you wish to use  the `on()` as stated in your question, use [`$(this).off('click');`](https://api.jquery.com/off/) to remove the event listener after the fist press:

```js
$( ".container" ).on( "click", function() {
  alert( "The event happened!" );
  $(this).off('click');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class= "container">Container</div>
```